# Configuration to use Swiper as an ES module

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Related: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3005

I'm facing a bug where when using `watchOverflow` with `slidesOffsetBefore/slidesOffsetAfter`, swiper does not prevent swipe when there is no overflow as per

https://codepen.io/m11x/pen/OeaGpP

I understand that in the git issue #3005, this was fixed as per 5.1.0 as seen on this repo that I've created (minus the cat pictures)

https://codepen.io/xavianaxw/pen/ZEEwbbz

I'm currently trying to port over this behaviour to my code using the ES module version of Swiper (which I know includes some configuration with my babel as mentioned at http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/ under "At an ES module" section)

Here's what my babel config look like in my webpack.

```
{
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(dom7|ssr-window|swiper)\/).*/,
  options: { presets: [["env", { "modules": false }], 'stage-1'] },
  test: /(\.js$|.jsx$)/
}
```

and in my javascript

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';

const swiper = new Swiper(this.elements.swiper, {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  watchOverflow: true,
  spaceBetween: 5,
  slidesOffsetBefore: 10,
  slidesOffsetAfter: 10,
});
```

With my setup above, I'm not able to get `watchOverflow` to work. This will however work if I just import the CDN version at the top but obviously it's not what I'm trying to achieve.